# Missing required parameters for [Route: viewticketuser] [URI: viewticketuser/{id}]. // LARAVEL 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-7

When I click the submit button this page appears: Missing required parameters for [Route: viewticketuser] [URI: viewticketuser/{id}]
When at first sight when I only wanted to appear all the tickets the update button worked correctly then when I made for each user it occurs an error

View:

```
        @foreach($ticket as $user)
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$user->ticket_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->description}}</td>

                <td>{{$user->status}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->assigned_user_id_fk}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->created_at}}</td>
                <td>
                    <form action="{{ route('updateticketadmin',$user->ticket_id) }}" method="post">

                                @csrf


                                <select class="form-control" name="status">

                            <option value=0>0</option>
                            <option value=1>1</option>
                        </select>


                        <button style="width: 100%" type="submit" class="block btn btn-success">Change Status</button>
                    </form>

                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        @endforeach
```

web.php:

```
    Route::post('updateticketadmin/{id}','TicketController@updatestatusadmin')->name('updateticketadmin')->middleware('is_admin');
```

Controller:

```
public function updatestatusadmin(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $request->validate([
            $status='status' => 'required',
        ]);
        $status=(int)$status;



        return redirect()->route('ticketshow')->with('Success', 'Status Changed Succesfully!');

    }
```

Comment: your problem is in this `viewticketuser/{id}` url and you haven't shared it. and the update function of your controller is not in your question too. so add those to your question.

Comment: ` public function updatestatusadmin(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $request->validate([
            $status='status' => 'required',
        ]);
        $status=(int)$status;



        Ticket::where('ticket_id', $id)->update(array('status' => $status));


        return redirect()->route('ticketshow')->with('Success', 'Status Changed Succesfully!');

    }`

Comment: the form action url should take you to the `TicketController`'s `update` function not `updatestatusadmin`

Comment: @zahidhasanemon i edited that part but still not function